# Size of Centers of groups of order 288

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

How can I list the sizes of centers of groups of order $288$ in GAP? By GAP we know that there are $1045$ groups of this order by the command below:

```
G:=AllSmallGroups(288);;
```

I want to obtain `Size(Center(G[i]))` for $i = 1, \dots, 1045$
, respectively.

In fact I want to compute the difference between values of `Size(Center(G[i]))` and `NrConjugacyClasses` of corresponding `G[i]`, for $i = 1, \dots, 1045$.

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: By looping over all of the 1045 groups, I would guess?

Comment: If this is just about how to make GAP do this, then it is not a very good fit for this site, but I would suggest you look up the List function.

Comment: It is time-consuming. I want a command or program which shows the list immediately. Like List(G,NrConjugacyClasses).

Comment: Does this really take more than a few minutes?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: In fact I want to compute the difference between values of NrConjugacyClasses of G[i] and Size(Center(G[i])) for i=1,...,1045, which is time-consuming. Is there a function to compute this?

Comment: Computing that difference took about 10-20 second on my 5-year old laptop.

Comment: How do you compute that? with which commands? Would you please send me the commands you use?

Comment: As I said, just use the List command.

Comment: You can use the `List` command in the same way: `List(G,x->Size(Center(x)));`   The `x->` is short hand notation for a 1-argument function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I do; I don't know more shortcult commands (but there are)!

```
G:=AllSmallGroups(288);;
l:=[ ];;
for i in [1..Size(G)] do
    Add(l, Size(Center(G[i])));
od;
l;
```

Comment: This is pretty much what the command List does (thought it might be implemented in a way that works slightly faster).

Comment: yes; I have never practised it, but I have heard of it, so said "I don't know" but "there are!"

Comment: @p Groups: It didn't work on my laptop. There is no output with this function.

Comment: @M.R. Right, you need to ask it to output the list is has generated.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: I am amateur in GAP. Would you please tell me how can i see the output?

Comment: type  this thing-   l;

Comment: This is not what I want. This is the set of values that appear in the set of sizes of centers of G[i]. But what I need is the list of sizes of centers of corresponding G[i], respectively. In fact I want to compute the difference between values of Size(Center(G[i])) and NrConjugacyClasses of corresponding G[i]  for i=1,...,1045.

Comment: @M.R. Then subtract one from the other. They are listed in the same order as the groups by construction.

Comment: This is the output:                                                                                         gap> G:=AllSmallGroups(288);;
gap> l:=[ ];;
gap> for i in [1..Size(G)] do
> AddSet(l, Size(Center(G[i])));od;
gap> l;
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 24, 36, 48, 72, 288 ]

Comment: @M.R. Ohh, actually, you should use Add instead of AddSet to get what I just said

Comment: What do you want then? Doesn't it answer's your question?

Comment: @Beginner: I have the set of NrConjugacyClasses of G[i] and the set of sizes of centers of G[i]. I need the subtraction of elements of these two sets.

Comment: @M.R. Did you understand how those sets were computed? From that it is pretty straightforward to get what you need.

Comment: gap> for i in [1..Size(G)] do .....  gap> a:=NrConjugacyClasses(G[i]); ..... b:=Size(Center(G[i]));.... AddSet( l ,  [ i, a, b, a-b ] );.... fi;.... od; [I have written commands with gap of dots; these dots should not be considered in program. I think you will understood this modification of program of pGroups.)

Comment: @Beginner. Thank You.

Comment: Note that shorter code may not be the most efficient one, especially if `NrSmallGroups(n)` is very large. You can iterate like `for i in [1..NrSmallGroups(n)] do g:=SmallGroup(n,i); ... od`. Also sometimes `SmallGroupsInformation` gives useful insights into how the groups of a given order are arranged in the library. I suggest to look at [Software Carpentry lesson on GAP](http://alex-konovalov.github.io/gap-lesson/05-small-groups/) for some sample code.

Comment: @ Alexander Konovalov. The link was very useful. Thank you for it.